# How do I remove woocommerce products after time?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, webshop

Im currently building a webshop using woocommerce ([icondesignliving](http://www.icondesignliving.se/butik/))
and the customer wants the products to be automatically removed after time. Or after a certain date, Is it possible to do this, if yes, how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a plugin called [Post Expirator](https://wordpress.org/plugins/post-expirator/).
When you add or edit a product there will be a `Post Expirator` box on the right hand side, which will allow you to choose if the product can be hidden after a certain date. Choose what date it will hidden on and what is to happen to the product (draft, delete, set it to private, or change category):

[image]

Comment: Well I only want it to show one certain time, but I saw you can mod it, so I will try that, thanks for the help!